# Exclude a swift file from XCode code coverage

Tags: ios, swift, apollo, apollo-ios

I am using Apollo SDK, which generates an API.swift file. Can we exclude this file from the code coverage

Comment: Short answer: no, you can only exclude target. But you can get creative: put that file in its own target, or move it to test target for tests (test target is typically excluded from coverage)

Answer (score 2):

You can't exclude files from code coverage report directly in Xcode.
You can use external tools like [xcov](https://github.com/fastlane-community/xcov) or [slather](https://github.com/SlatherOrg/slather) to generate HTML version of report and set list of excluded files in its config file.

Comment: I can't make xcov read excluded files, there are several issues reported in github. I am not sure xcov is the solution at the moment

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in codecov.yml (external tools)

...
...
...

ignore:

- "path-for-file-to-ignore"

Answer (score 0):

you can use the built in one `llvm-cov` and you can specify it with the `--ignore-filename-regex` parameter.

here is an example (and a demo project):

https://github.com/michaelhenry/swifty-code-coverage

with the coverage that you get from llvm-cov, you can have the option to display it in the stdout or a file or just push it somewhere like codecov or codeclimate

here is the file to be exact

https://github.com/michaelhenry/swifty-code-coverage/blob/main/lcov.sh

so you can either `report`, `export` or both the code coverage.

```
$ xcrun llvm-cov export --help
```

[image]

Cheers,